In Playwright, how do you wait until one of two selectors appear?
I want to wait until either an error or the image appears after uploading.
The use-case is after an image upload, it will either display a textual error selectable with #message span or redirect with "Location:" header to a page with the image selectable with #image.
So I thought something like :
  await page.waitForSelector('#message, img#image', { timeout: 15000 });

But it still fails with
@upload.spec.ts:69
TimeoutError: page.waitForSelector: Timeout 15000ms exceeded.
Call log:
  - waiting for locator('#message, img#image') to be visible
  -   locator resolved to 2 elements. Proceeding with the first one: <span id="message" class="displayNone"></span>
  -   locator resolved to 2 elements. Proceeding with the first one: <span id="message" class="displayNone"></span>
  -   locator resolved to 2 elements. Proceeding with the first one: <span id="message" class="displayNone"></span>
(...)

Even though the image is clearly visible.
If I just wait for the image it works (when successful).
I need :

a long timeout
the two elements being of different types
either one of them becomes visible

Thanks!

This question is similar to: How can I wait until elements matching multiple selectors appear?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Code looks OK--it should work--but the page behavior is unclear. Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

The title of "How can I wait until elements matching multiple selectors appear?" makes it unclear what they want and for searching... they should have used the word "either" or "one of" or "one element" instead of "elements".

This worked
await page.locator('#message, img#image').isVisible( { timeout: 15000 });

I'm not sure why page.waitForSelector would throw a timeout.

I think I know what happened. page.waitForSelector() sees #message but it's 0 pixel of width thus not visible. Then it gets stuck waiting for this one to become visible but it never does. However image becomes visible but waitForSelector ditched it for #message as its log trace indicates "locator resolved to 2 elements. Proceeding with the first one:"

You can make use of Playwright's or locator method, which will resolve to either option. An example here:
const messageLocator = page.locator('#message');
const imageLocator = page.locator('#img#image');
await expect(messageLocator.or(imageLocator)).toBeVisible();
if (await messageLocator.isVisible()) await doSomethingForError();

// Rest of test

